# Why do I need to get the JCE to be able to handle keys larger than 128 bit?

Tags: java, security, policy, jce

Why do I need to get the **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files** to be able to handle keys larger than 128 bit? Why is it not bundled with Java SE?

Comment: Downvoted without an explanation? Please tell me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally due to US export laws, which were mostly repealed during the Clinton administration. Now it is due to the *import* laws of various other countries.

Comment: How does Java SE differ from JCE beside it is an extension? What is that is prohibited to be exported/imported?

Comment: JCE was originally an extension of J2SE but it got folded in. The prohibition is/was on cryptographic algorithms beyond a certain strength.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to US export laws. Probably.

Comment: What is that they cannot "export"? How does JCE differ from Java SE? I know JCE is an extension but are the algorithm considered US property and then cannot be exported?

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States